# Verificar a existência dos valores de um array nas keys de outro

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho dois arrays:

**$keys**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {3}
            [1] => {1}
            [2] => {2}
            [3] => {0}
            [4] => {4}
            [5] => {5}
        )

);
```

**$properties**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => var::terms::
            [1] => var::create_terms >> 1::
            [2] => const::EXAMPLE123::
            [3] => var::create_terms>>0::
            [4] => text::serio mesmo::
            [5] => ::ENTER::
        )

    ... // outras keys que não estão relacionadas

)
```

E gostaria de saber qual maneira é a mais correta e recomendada em termos de perfomance e semântica, verificar a existência dos valores do array 1 (sem `{}` colchetes) nas keys do array 2 (**Tenho dois exemplos**)

```php
$keys[1] = array_map(function ($keys) {
    return str_replace(['{', '}'], null, $keys);
}, $keys[0]);
sort($keys[1]);

if (in_array($keys[1], [array_keys($properties[0])], false)) {...} else {...}
```

OU

```php
$keys[1] = array_map(function ($keys) {
    return str_replace(['{', '}'], null, $keys);
}, $keys[0]);

foreach ($keys[1] as $key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $properties[0])) {...} else {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar a função `array_intersect()` para saber quais valores os arrays tem em comum, `array_flip()` é utilizado para inverter o par chave/valor.

```
<?php
$arr1[0] = [10,28,99];
$arr2[0] = ['var::terms::', 10 => ' var::create_terms >> 1::' , 99 => 'const::EXAMPLE123::', 28 =>'var::create_terms>>0::'];

$novo = array_intersect($arr1[0], array_flip($arr2[0]));
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 28
    [2] => 99
)
```

Ou ainda montar o processo inverso:

```
<?php
$arr1[0] = [10,28];
$arr2[0] = ['var::terms::', 10 => ' var::create_terms >> 1::' , 99 => 'const::EXAMPLE123::', 28 =>'var::create_terms>>0::'];
$novo = array_intersect_key($arr2[0], array_flip($arr1[0]));
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [10] =>  var::create_terms >> 1::
    [28] => var::create_terms>>0::
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que eu faria algo simples assim:

```
$keys = array(
    0 => array(
        '{3}',
        '{1}',
        '{2}',
        '{5}'
    ),
);

$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 'foo 0',
        1 => 'foo 1',
        2 => 'foo 2',
        3 => 'foo 3'
    ),
);

$rs = array();
foreach ($keys[0] as $v) {
    $k = (int)$v;
    if (isset($arr[0][$k])) {
        $rs[] = $k;
    }
}

if (!empty($rs)) {
    print_r($rs);
} else {
    echo 'nothing';
}
```

Não testei técnicas diferentes para poder dizer se é mais performático que uma técnica X ou Y. Prefiro usar coisas simples, onde até um inexperiente na linguagem consegue entender sem muito esforço pois isso facilita a manutenção.

Talvez o que pode dar uma otimizada é a maneira como os valores das chaves estão no primeiro array `$keys`.

Se não houver necessidade em guardar esses valores com as chaves `{}`, então não tem por que ter as chaves. Uma vez resolvido isso, poderia eliminar esse processo: `$k = (int)$v;`. 
É uma economia irrisória mas de qualquer forma, qualquer milionésimo de segundo é uma vantagem.

<sub>nota: Outro ponto é análise do contexto. Dependendo de onde e como esse trecho de código é aplicado, muitas vezes, uma revisão na estrutura pode até evitar esse processo ou pode existir formas melhores de resolver. Como sou alheio as condições e circunstâncias, me abstenho em comentar e mantive o foco somente no trecho de código proposto na pergunta.</sub>

Comment: Se manter as mesmas keys, podem transformar em array com `array_keys()` e depois usar `array_compare()` ou `array_intersect()` para ver se há diferenças entre um e outro.

Comment: Acho que consumiria mais processos usando essas funções, @William Aparecido Brandino.

Comment: Concordo, @DanielOmine, há várias formas de verificar se um existe em outro. Essa é uma.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer só com um foreach, e ir vendo de as chaves existem uma a uma:

```
$hey1 = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => '{2}',
        1 => '{3}',
        2 => '{0}',
        3 => '{2}'
    )
);

$hey2 = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 'dwe',
        1 => 'dwed',
        2 => 'dsa'
    ),
);

foreach($hey1[0] as $key1 => $value1) {
    $key2 = str_replace(['{', '}'], '', $value1);
    if(in_array($key2, array_keys($hey2[0]))) {
        echo $key1. ' => ' .$value1. ' existe: (' .$key2. ' => ' .$hey2[0][$key2]. ')<br>';
        continue;
    }
    echo $key1. ' => ' .$value1. ' não existe<br>';
}
```